# removing duplicate rows and dependencies without cursor

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, optimization, cursor, sql-server-2016

I have a table that has a long list of duplicated items. I am working on a stored procedure to consolidate them all into one record. Each one of the duplicated items has a number of child tables that should either be deleted, or rekeyed to point at the resulting record. My table has an Id, but the ReadableIdentifier is the column I need to deduplicate.

```
Id | ReadableIdentifier | Name        | UpdatedOn
1  | ABC1234            | Product X   | 2014-04-25 16:00:08.000
2  | ABC1234            | Product X   | 2014-04-28 16:00:08.000
3  | ABC1234            | Product X   | 2014-04-21 16:00:08.000
4  | ABDD9945           | Widget R    | 2014-04-25 16:00:08.000
5  | ABDD9945           | Widget R    | 2014-04-25 18:45:08.000
```

As you can see, records 1-3 are duplicates with different Id's and UpdatedOn dates. Same for 4-5. I need to consolidate these into one record, preferring the one with the most recent UpdatedOn date.

End Goal (not showing children tables):

```
Id | ReadableIdentifier | Name        | UpdatedOn
2  | ABC1234            | Product X   | 2014-04-28 16:00:08.000
5  | ABDD9945           | Widget R    | 2014-04-25 18:45:08.000
```

I am using a `CURSOR` to do this, but am wondering if there is a better solution.

```
DECLARE dupeCursor CURSOR 
    FAST_FORWARD
FOR 
    WITH Counts AS (
        SELECT
            COUNT(1) Count,
            ReadableIdentifier
        FROM dbo.Item WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE ReadableIdentifier IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY ReadableIdentifier)
    SELECT
        Counts.Count, 
        Counts.ReadableIdentifier,
        Counts.CompanyId
    FROM
        Counts
    WHERE Counts.Count > 1;

OPEN dupeCursor;
DECLARE @readableId VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @itemToPersistId INT, @itemToDeleteId INT;
FETCH NEXT FROM dupeCursor INTO @readableId;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

   WITH V AS (
      SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ReadableId ORDER BY UpdatedOn DESC) as Row
        FROM dbo.Item WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ReadableId = @readableId
   )
   SELECT @itemToPersistId = Id
   FROM V
   WHERE V.Row = 1

   CREATE TABLE #itemsToDelete (Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
   INSERT INTO #itemsToDelete
   SELECT Id
   FROM dbo.Item WITH (NOLOCK)
   WHERE ReadableId = @readableId AND Id != @itemToPersistId;

   --UPDATE CHILDREN TABLES
   DELETE FROM dbo.ItemDetails WHERE ItemId IN (SELECT Id FROM #itemsToDelete);

   UPDATE dbo.ItemPurchases SET ItemId = @itemToPersistId 
   WHERE ItemId IN (SELECT Id FROM #itemsToDelete); 

   UPDATE dbo.PurchaseOrders SET ItemId = @itemToPersistId 
   WHERE ItemId IN (SELECT Id FROM #itemsToDelete); 

   DELETE FROM dbo.ItemMetadata WHERE ItemId IN (SELECT Id FROM #itemsToDelete); 

   --delete Duplicated Items
   DELETE FROM dbo.Item WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM #itemsToDelete);

   DROP TABLE #itemsToDelete

   FETCH NEXT FROM dupeCursor INTO @readableId;
END

CLOSE dupeCursor;
DEALLOCATE dupeCursor;
```

I realize the cursor is most likely the issue, but I'm not sure how to go about updating all of the child tables without using one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I dont have data to test this for the child tables but it should work:

```
WITH V
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ReadableId ORDER BY UpdatedOn DESC) AS Row
         FROM dbo.Item WITH (NOLOCK))
     SELECT *
     INTO #itemsToDelete
     FROM V;

--UPDATE CHILDREN TABLES
DELETE FROM dbo.ItemDetails
WHERE ItemId IN
(
    SELECT Id
    FROM #itemsToDelete
    WHERE Row > 1
);
UPDATE IP
  SET
      IP.ItemId = itk.ID
FROM dbo.ItemPurchases AS IP
     INNER JOIN #itemsToDelete AS itd ON IP.ItemId = itd.ID
                                         AND itd.Row > 1
     INNER JOIN #itemsToDelete AS itk ON itk.ReadableIdentifier = itd.ReadableIdentifier
                                         AND itk.Row = 1
                                         AND itd.Row > 1;
UPDATE po
  SET
      po.ItemId = itk.ID
FROM dbo.PurchaseOrders AS po
     INNER JOIN #itemsToDelete AS itd ON po.ItemId = itd.ID
                                         AND itd.Row > 1
     INNER JOIN #itemsToDelete AS itk ON itk.ReadableIdentifier = itd.ReadableIdentifier
                                         AND itk.Row = 1
                                         AND itd.Row > 1;
DELETE FROM dbo.ItemMetadata
WHERE ItemId IN
(
    SELECT Id
    FROM #itemsToDelete
    WHERE Row > 1
); 

--delete Duplicated Items
DELETE FROM dbo.Item
WHERE Id IN
(
    SELECT Id
    FROM #itemsToDelete
    WHERE Row > 1
);
```

Comment: Right, I have this done already. How would I go about running the UPDATE/DELETEs on the children tables without using a CURSOR?

Comment: is Id a foreign key in the other tables?

Comment: Yes, see the statements in my question.

Comment: @gwin003 have a look at the newest edit to my answer. Unfortunately I don't have data for the child tables to test this but at least you'll get the idea of how to do it using a set based approach

Comment: @gwin003 I suggest changing the title of your question to "removing duplicate rows and dependencies without CURSOR" or something to the fact

Comment: Thank you @Kamran Farzami, this worked perfectly and I saw a pretty big speed increase going this route.

Comment: You're welcome. Set based operations are almost always faster.